# noob mac user - developer directory conventions

Tags: macos, configuration, convention

I just got a Mac Mini OS X Server. This is my first foray into the Mac world. Wanting to get off on the right foot as I configure my machine, which will be used principally for software development (java, groovy, grails, javascript, etc.), I am wondering what conventions are typically followed as you install software tools, locate your projects, etc. I have tried googling this question, using a variety of search terms, but none of the pages comes up with answers near to what it is I am asking. I am not asking about where tools that come with an installer (an image, as I understand it). No, **my first question is about installing things like tomcat, mysql, or similar**, things that need me to intervene and select a location.

My second question, then, is: where do I place my projects that I am developing? I am thinking that these should probably go to a subdirectory of my home directory, one called **projects**, perhaps?

Is there anything else I should know as I go about configuring my Mac for development? Are there tools/utilities that I should install that are unique to the Mac world (in other words, don't suggest tools like Firefox plugins that I would have likely used on a PC)?

Thanks!

Comment: It's mostly a question on "how install a server" which is for serverfault.com and "how to work with a mac" which is for superuser.com  And for my part my dev projects are in `~/Documents/Development/{Language}/{project}` (replace `{Language}` by the main language used in the project and `{project}` by the project name.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main thing is to stick to the 'site local' areas; /usr/local/* and /Library/*. Of course anything under a user's home is perfectly safe as well. Doing this should keep you out of trouble with respect to software updates from Apple. Sometimes you need some environment variable changes to allow your software to pick up e.g. additional $PATH elements.

Regarding useful tools, I like the package manager Mac Ports. It's often a fast way to fill out a dependency chain or experiment with various software packages.

Comment: I was looking at a description for installing tomcat. They listed /usr/local and /Applications as the preferred locations, and the sample used the latter. The former seems rather consistently referenced, from what I have seen. After further research I did find something called the File System Hierarchy Standard (http://www.pathname.com/fhs/pub/fhs-2.3.html). The standard, if I understand it properly, suggests /usr/local structure. The standard does go on to discuss the subdirectory hierarchy here as well. I will abide by that.